# JQuery undefined response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, getjson

I have the notion that this is very easy and over-documented, but I have been at this for hours on end and I just don't get it!  All I want to do is return the result of a $.getJSON query.  It works fine if I append it to a div etc, but if I try to just get the result, I can alert it in the callback function, but not anywhere else.  I think my code will show what I am trying to do:

```
var thumb = 
              $.getJSON('http://localhost/mapScripts/getThumbs.php?thumbnails=?',
function(data) { 
alert(data); //shows the result perfect!
var thumb = data; 
return thumb;

});

alert(thumb); //undefined
```

Sorry in advance if it seems like such a silly question, but I haven't been able to get it :(

Many thanks for your time,

elshae

**EDIT**
Meder and David both gave me great answers.  I'd like to mark both as my answer, but it seems I can only choose one :-/.  Anyone having this issue, please look at both answers :)

Comment: Could you post you'r answer aswell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made a couple of different attempts to get the data here, and they fail for different reasons. I'll explain why in a moment, first though — the solution:

**Whatever you do with the data has to be done in the callback function.**

Now, why your attempts don't work:

You can't return data from an Ajax request.

Ajax works (usually) by creating an XHR object, setting an event handler for "When the request comes back", and then sending an HTTP request.

You can't return data from it for the same reason that you can't get the event object returned from:

```
var not_the_event = jQuery('foo').click(function (event) { return event; });
```

You can't set the value of a variable called `thumb` and defined outside a function from inside a function that defines `thumb` using the `var` keyword. The `var` keyword creates a new instance of the variable that is scoped to the function.

If you took the `var` away from the callback function, it still wouldn't work because you would have timing issues.

If you had:

```
var not_the_event;
jQuery('foo').click(function (event) { not_the_event = event; });
alert(not_the_event);
```

Then you would be alerting `undefined` because the click hasn't taken place when the `alert` is called, so the variable hasn't been set by the event handling function.

With Ajax, the HTTP request hasn't been answered by the time the alert is reached, so it is also undefined.

Which brings us back to: Whatever you do with the data has to be done in the callback function.

The point of the callback function is that it is called when the data is ready. So whatever you do with the data can be done then.

Comment: I really like this answer! However, I am still not able to get it to work. Now I tried : `var icon; $.getJSON('http://localhost/mapScripts/getThumbs.php?thumbnails=?', function(data) {icon = new OpenLayers.Icon(data);}); alert(icon); //still undefined` and I also tried: `var icon = $.getJSON('http://localhost/mapScripts/getThumbs.php?thumbnails=?', function(data) {var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon(data); return icon;}); alert(icon); //also undefined :(`

Comment: This is failing for the same reason. You have stuff that runs immediately after the request is made dependent on data that doesn't exist until the response comes back. You've just moved the *first* of the things that depend on that data inside the callback. You need **everything** there.

Comment: I'm sorry maybe some sort of example? I guess I'm just not getting it...because it still doesn't work :(

Comment: `jQuery.getJSON('http://localhost/mapScripts/getThumbs.php?thumbnails=?', function(data) {var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon(data); alert(icon) });`

Comment: Short of calling a different function and passing the data to it, there is no way to get the data out. Hence "Whatever you do with the data has to be done in the callback function."

Comment: So if I understand correctly, your suggesting I do what meder had suggested above?  

Make an external function that uses the `thumb` variable and call it inside of the one you have

Comment: Assuming that by "uses" you mean: `function foo(thumb) { … }` and `jQuery.getJSON('http://localhost/mapScripts/getThumbs.php?thumbnails=?', function(data) { foo(data) });`. Then that is a decent approach.

Comment: This is my attempt @ that approach, but still a no-go

`function makeThumbs(data){
    icon = new OpenLayers.Icon(data);
    markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(93.9, 29.53),icon));
   }
   
   $.getJSON('http://localhost/mapScripts/getThumbs.php?thumbnails=?', function(data) {makeThumbs(data);});`

Comment: It's not that there is an error message, but rather nothing happens.  Unfortunately I am forced to leave my desk this moment and for the rest of the weekend.  I am so thankful for your help and I will post the correct code as soon as I get it.  I'm marking you and Meder as the answers..

Comment: `function foo(thumb) { … } and jQuery.getJSON('http://localhost/mapScripts/getThumbs.php?thumbnails=?', function(data) { foo(data) });` This worked like a charm!  I tried again with fresh eyes and I got it!  Thank you so much for your time and efforts.  I have a much clearer understanding now of asynchronous methods and will be able to catch this pitfall in the future :)

Answer (score 3):

Ajax is asynchronous. Instead of relying on `thumb` just call a function in the callback and do the same functionality.

```
var thumb = data;
anotherFunction( thumb );
```

Otherwise, if are insistent upon this structure, specify `async:false` though that kills the whole benefit of Ajax.

Comment: `var thumb = $.getJSON('http://localhost/mapScripts/getThumbs.php?thumbnails=?', function(data) {var thumb = data; function (thumb){return thumb;}});`

I'm not sure what you mean...but I tried this...resulted in errors :(

"do the same functionality" Sorry not sure what that means...

Comment: Make an **external** function that uses the `thumb` variable and call it inside of the one you have.

Answer (score 0):

you defined it locally, if you want it to work globally, define it globally:

```
var thumb = {};
$.getJSON('http://localhost/mapScripts/getThumbs.php?thumbnails=?',
function(data) { 
alert(data); //shows the result perfect!
thumb = data; 

});

alert(thumb);
```

Though as others have posted it's better to have the call back pass it to another function since relying on globals is a bad practice. And the alert would trigger before the ajax was done.

Comment: Well it's definitely closer than what I had before...now I got `[object object]` :(.  but many thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't define second variable with the same name in inner scope :)

Regarding to your problem add following line before you call '$.getJSON':

$.ajaxSetup({ async: false });

Comment: I'd rather not use `$.ajaxSetup({ async: false });`, but nonetheless I appreciate your thoughtful feedback and yes I made a mistake naming my variables like that :p